# Custom registry key deleted on reboot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, reboot

I have made a custom **registry key** (String Value) for identification of which computer a user logs on to. The problem is that this key is deleted whenever the computer is rebooted.

The key is entered under 
`Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`

I have already tried to set myself as the owner and gave my account all the permissions possible like read/write, however it is a strong possibility that I did that wrong.

Comment: As an extra bit of information, the ownership and permissions have been reset when i reboot the computer as well.

Comment: Does the same happen when you create key in another place (for example in `HKCU`)>

Comment: when i made keys in `HKCU` they did not delete on reboot. This can work for what i want to do, but out of curiosity do you know why it deleted it from `HKLM`?

Comment: Hmm are you running regedit (or your software) as admin?

Comment: both are being run as administrator, i didn't press run as administrator but i did have to approve it to make changes on my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem (if we can call it so) is in Windows Registry architecture.
HKLM hive doesn't exist on your computer. On each boot Windows "virtually" assembles that hive from some files which are located in `\Windows\System32\Config` folder. So any key created directly in HKLM will not be stored.

But if you create a key inside existing subfolders of HKLM, it will be saved.
If you still want to create a key in HKLM, I recomend you to create it in `HKLM\Software`, for example in: 
`HKLM\Software\YourKeyFolder\YourKey`
Other subfolders are dangerous and may require higher privileges, so playing with them can damage the system or can cause serious security problems. If you want to know more, read [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/termshm/g/hkey_local_machine.htm) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).